# Как разбить выполнение кода с библиотекой OpenGL на видеокарту и процессор. C++

Tags: c++, opengl

Хочу сделать так, что бы часть кода с OpenGL выполнялась в процессоре, а не весь код в видеокарте, так как видеокарта у меня слабая, а процессор более менее нормальный.

Comment: В теории можно сделать программный контекст OpenGL и рисовать на процессоре, однако если это не какой-нибудь EPYC, то даже слабая видеокарта без проблем его уделает.

Comment: А вы профилировщиком смотрели, насколько загружены CPU и GPU?